# Change pagination kartik yii2

Tags: yii, pagination, yii2

[image: my pagination]

How can make this pagination show all the number of page. I mean, i want to show 1 until 25 when i have 25 page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer, I change `LInkPager.php` file on

```
public $maxButtonCount = 30;
```

30 means the maximal page you want to show.